# bash function call with arguments within test function

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing

I want to call a function with arguments within the test function (()) and act according to the exit code.

```
function f { return
}
```

Works: call function within test function (()) without arguments and test exit code:

```
((f)) || echo ok   <-- UPDATE: the function isn't called but (undefined) variable f is evaluated to 0
```

Works: call function with argument(s) and test exit code

```
f 1 && echo ok
```

Works: test function (()) with an expression:

```
((1+1)) && echo ok
```

Does't work: call function with argument(s) within test function (()) and test exit code:

```
((f 1)) || echo ok <-- UPDATE: no call of function f, but f evaluated to 0
```

syntax error in expression (error token is "1")

**UPDATE**: the above approach doesn't make sense, because the function f is not called within (())

What I have:

```
if ((var)); then
  f arg1 arg2 agr3
  if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    ...
  fi
fi
```

What I want: Only one logical expression with AND, checking both conditions.
And execute f only after var has been evaluated, so not:

```
f arg1 arg2 arg3
if [[ ($? != 0) && ($var != 0) ]]; then ...
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass an argument to the function? you're telling it to run two commands there

Comment: @bobdylan yes, I want to pass arguments to the function, that is the case. And then use the result in an expression. Is it just a syntax error, or can't I pass args to functions in general when called within an expression?

Comment: isn't it just `(( $(f 1) )) || echo ok`?

Comment: Why do you need to call function in arithmetic environment `((`?

Comment: stand-alone arithmetic `((f))` will not call function `f` but evaluate `f` as a number. If you need to call function `f` within the arithmetic expression: `(($(f)))` then the output of function `f` will be treated as a value. Although the return code of `f` will be ignored.

Comment: @jamacoe, you _can_. Interestingly, the following works for me in bash: `((f 1);) || echo ok` (note the semicolon)

Comment: @leagris I made the mistake to think that ((f)) is called. It's a var and as not being defined it was evaluated to 0, leading me to think that it is the exit code. Setting the function return to 1 clarified this.

Comment: @michalH I thought I could threat the return code as an integer to work with, but as LeaGris pointed out, the function isn't being called at all.

Comment: @pyr0 yes, I would have the function to echo some result, but I was trying to evaluate the exit code instead.

Comment: So you want `if var=$(f 1) && ((var))`? I do not understand. `within test function (())` There is no such thing as "test function" `((...))` is _arithmetic expression_.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. `&&` and `||` already treat the exit status as an integer (although, only to make a zero-vs-nonzero distinction).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if ((var)); then
>   f arg1 arg2 agr3
>   if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
>     ...
>   fi
> fi
> ```
>
> What I want: Only one logical expression with AND, checking both conditions.

Just:

```
if ((var)) && ! f arg1 arg2 agr3; then
```

As a general rule, try not to use `$?` at all - just test the results of commands inside `if`.

Comment: Great! This leads to an answer to my initial question. Written with ternary style this is (((var)) && ! f 1 2 3) && echo "genial". Eliminating '((var))', '&&' and '!' leaves (f 1 2 3) && echo "genial". So there you have it: ((f)) evaluates the variable f, but (f) calls the function f, and I can even eliminate these last brackets.

Comment: `(f) calls the function f,` - `(f)` creates a subshell and then inside that subshell the function `f` is evaluated. That's different then `{f;}` or `f` which would "just" call function `f`.

Comment: Very useful distinguations. Thanks to these I was able to 'compose' the following statement (I know it is unreadable, just for the sake of demonstration): ! { { iface=$(grep -om1 "wl[^\t]\+" <<< $(ls /sys/class/net)); } && { grep -q "up" /sys/class/net/$iface/operstate; } } && { echo "NO WLAN"; exit 1; }

Comment: `<<< $(..)` - use `< <(..)` instead. Yes - variable assignment in subshell are not visible in parent shell. (and also, `exit` exits the subshell, not parent shell)